# How to add and iOS7 support to iOS8 compatibility version in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, minimum-requirements

My app is already in App Store. It is only compatible for ios 8.0. When someone with an earlier version try to download the app he receives this message: "requires ios 8" My code already checks for the different ios versions when loading resources. But what do I have to do in Xamarin and iTunesConnect to add make the minimum OS version 7 instead of 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project's iOS Application options, set "Deployment Target" to 7.0